# Why are both parts of $\forall a, b \in X,\ a R b \lor b R a.$ necessary for the definition of Total Order

Tags: elementary-set-theory

On [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_relation) wiki page it has this definition of a total order: $$\forall a, b \in X,\ a R b \lor b R a.$$
My understanding of $a$ and $b$ is that if $R$ is the relation of less than or equal to on $\mathbb{R}$, than $a$ can be any element in $\mathbb{R}$ and b can be any element in $\mathbb{R}$. What I want to understand is why both $a R b$ and $b R a$ are necessary for the definition. From my ignorance, $a R b$ is equivalent to $a R b \lor b R a$ since any $a$ could equal $b$ and stating the same thing twice with a $\lor$ is redundant. Now, what incredibly basic thing am i not understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you’re missing is that what follows the universal quantifier must be true for **every** possible assignment of values to $a$ and $b$. The quantifier $\forall a,b\in\Bbb R$, for instance, includes the possibility that $a=3$ and $b=2$; if the relation $R$ is $\le$, it simply isn’t true that $a\le b$ for that particular assignment of values to $a$ and $b$, since in fact $3\not\le 2$.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you

Comment: @ludragon: You’re welcome.